# How to select two table-cells by clicking on one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a table with time schedule, where user need to choose which  time he wants to book by selecting one or more option. I want to realize this by dragging highlighted cells. The problem is that I don't know how to select automatically two cells (or more, by dragging to next cell) by clicking on one

I tried some jQuery plugins but they didn't work correctly. With them, user have an option to select one cell and this is not appropriate

For example, if user choose 11:00 it must select not just td with 11:00, but next one too (or more, depends of how many hours user wants to book)

```html
<table id="daily" class="example_default getArray" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>7:00</td>
    <td>8:00</td>
    <td class="ignore">9:00</td>
    <td class="ignore">10:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11:00</td>
    <td>12:00</td>
    <td>13:00</td>
    <td>14:00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Where is the JS/jQuery code, which you have tried?

Comment: So if you have to select two cells, the one clicked and the next one, what happens if I click `10:00`? I assume it would also select `11:00` on the next row? Similarly, what happens if I click `14:00`? There's no following cell to click. I'd suggest you think about a better way to present this selection to your users, eg. two fields, 1) start time 2) duration.

Comment: only the last one can be clicked single, others need to be in pair of two or more tds, as user choose

Comment: what happens if you click `8:00` as the next `td` is ignored ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this using the `next()` and `not` operator can help achieve this,

```js
$('td:not(.ignore)').on('click', (e) => {
  $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
  $(e.currentTarget).addClass('selected');
  $(e.currentTarget).next('td:not(.ignore)').addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table id="daily" class="example_default getArray" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>7:00</td>
    <td>8:00</td>
    <td class="ignore">9:00</td>
    <td class="ignore">10:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11:00</td>
    <td>12:00</td>
    <td>13:00</td>
    <td>14:00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: To remove the need to create the same jQuery object twice: `$(e.currentTarget).next('td:not(.ignore)').addBack().addClass('selected');`

Comment: That almost what I need! but I also need to have an ability drag them by mousedown to the next cell

Comment: @Afelip just out of curiosity, why would you over-complicate this with a drag feature? I mean is it really a good UX?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the previous answer of @Nidhin Joseph

```js
var clicked = false;

$('td:not(.ignore)').on('mousedown', (e) => {

  $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
  $(e.currentTarget).addClass('selected');
  clicked = true;

  $(document).on('mouseup', (e) => {
   clicked = false;
  });

}).on('mousemove', (e) => {

  if(clicked && ($(e.currentTarget).prev('td').hasClass('selected') || ($(e.currentTarget).is(':first-child') && $(e.currentTarget).parent().prev().find('td:not(.ignore)').last().hasClass('selected')))){
  $(e.currentTarget).addClass('selected');
  }

});
```

```css
.selected {
  background: red;
}

td{
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table id="daily" class="example_default getArray" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>7:00</td>
    <td>8:00</td>
    <td class="ignore">9:00</td>
    <td class="ignore">10:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11:00</td>
    <td>12:00</td>
    <td>13:00</td>
    <td>14:00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```